# Formatting LVM partition with HFS+

Tags: linux, partitioning, hfs

I've already tried fsck.hfsplus from hfsprogs, which doesn't do anything at all, and gparted (doesn't work with LVM). Are there any other ways to do that? If all else fails I have OSX install DVD, but I'm not sure if its installer would see a LVM partition (and running it just to check that would be quite troublesome, as I don't have a DVD drive ATM).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i figured it out using iSCSI (as in [this tutorial](http://www.toddsmith.org/wordpress/server-technology/iscsi-over-lvm-howto-os-x-initiator/)). Works with TM out of the box as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the same thing when using the built-in **Disk Utility** as you would see when running the Mac OS install DVD. Try Disk Utility first; maybe it can see the LVM partition; if it can, just reformat it as HFS+.

Comment: The thing is I have more data on this LVM setup... But I guess I'll have to do that after all. Would HFS+ work with logical partitions?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way of just changing the partition type without losing the data on it; so, just save the data somewhere, format as HFS+ (if possible) and copy the data back. It's the only way, in my opinion. I'm not sure about the logical partitions, sorry. I'm a bit over my head on that matter.